How can I connect a single task to multiple successors in a Gantt Chart?
I am trying to create a Gantt chart and one of my tasks has 2 successors. How can I prepare the data so the 2 lines to the successors are drawn?

It's possible to configure multiple connectors to represent tasks with more than one successor in a Gantt chart.
To achieve this, you can use the connector property in your data set to define connections between tasks. Below is an example:
{
  id: "1",
  name: "Task 1",
  actualStart: "2023-12-10",
  actualEnd: "2023-12-15",
  connector: [
    {
      connectTo: "2",
      connectorType: "finish-start"
    },
    {
      connectTo: "3",
      connectorType: "finish-start"
    }
  ]
}

This example demonstrates how Task 1 connects to Task 2 and Task 3 using the finish-start connector type.
For a practical demonstration, you can explore our Gantt chart with multiple task successors example on the AnyChart Playground, where the implementation details are available in lines 16–25.

This is EXACTLY what I needed! Thank you so much!
